# O que pode ser o erro?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not create service of type AnnotationProcessorDetector using JavaGradleScopeServices.createAnnotationProcessorDetector().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Rode com `--stacktrace` e coloque a saída para analisarmos. Conforme o que formos concluindo vamos solicitar algum trechos de código para verificação. OK?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo essa [issue do Github](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/4680), faça:

```
./gradlew compileJava recompile --stacktrace
```

Segundo esta [issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3708) tente: `gradle --stop` depois: `gradle --test` para reiniciar.

Se não funcionar tente:

Remover o diretório .gradle (linux):

```
./gradlew --stop
sudo rm .gradle/4.10.1/javaCompile/classAnalysis.bin 
rm -r build
rm -r app/build
sudo chown [username] .gradle/4.10.1/javaCompile
sudo chown [username] .gradle/4.10.1/javaCompile/*
./gradlew build
```

No windows você pode remover manualmente.

Se não funcionar tente o que este [pessoal recomenda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project):

Dê um `--stacktrace --info` para coletar mais informações sobre o problema, caso não encontre solução.